# Memory intensive operation

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to perform the following operation in pandas and dask:

1. Perform a cartesian product on the dataframe Network (containing 5000000 observations);
2. Delete from a database called SecondOrder_dd (having 1087597478 observations) the unmatched observations with the cartesian product database obtained in 1.
3. The result should be SecondOrder_dd with a lower number of observations

Since of course the whole process is memory and computational intensive I thought about dividing the Network database into smaller chunks, performing the cartesian product for each smaller chunks, merging it with SecondOrder_dd and keep the "left_only" observations. At each step I delete the unneeded intermediate results to free up memory as follows:

```
n=10000

#split DataFrame into chunks
list_df = [Network[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(Network),n)]

SecondOrder_dd2 = SecondOrder_dd

for k in range(len(list_df)):
    # Perform the join and filtering within each chunk
    df=list_df[k]
    merged_df = pd.merge(df, df, how='cross', suffixes=('', '_y'))
    merged_df = merged_df[['NiuSup', 'NiuCust', 'NiuCust_y']]
    merged_df.columns = ['NiuSup', 'NiuCust_x', 'NiuCust_y']
    # Keep only the relevant columns and rename
    merged_df = merged_df.drop(columns={"NiuSup"})
    merged_df = merged_df.rename(columns={"NiuCust_x": "NiuSup"})
    merged_df = merged_df.rename(columns={"NiuCust_y": "NiuCust"})
    merged_df = merged_df.query("NiuSup != NiuCust")
    merged_dd = dd.from_pandas(merged_df, npartitions=100).compute()
    
    del df, merged_df

    result_dd = dd.merge(SecondOrder_dd2, merged_dd, on=['NiuSup', 'NiuCust'], how='left', suffixes=('_left', '_right'), indicator=True)
    result_dd['_merge'] = result_dd['_merge'].map(lambda x: 'left_only' if x == 'left_only' else 'matched')
    SecondOrder_dd2 = result_dd[result_dd['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop(columns='_merge')
    #If we obtain the same dataframe as the original SecondOrder_dd_prova it means that no match was present

    del merged_dd, result_dd  # Free up memory by deleting the DataFrames
    print(k)
```

The problem is that even adopting this approach my kernel dies at some point meaning that still there are memory issues. However I cannot see where since at the end of the day what stays in memory should be a database smaller than SecondOrder_dd (I should delete every intermediate result).

Am I doing something wrong? Can I optimise the code?

Here some example data:

```
data = {
    'Niusup': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'Niucust': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
}

db = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi! Would you mind providing some example data with which we can run the code and see how it can be optimized?